# Adding a Jenkinsfile for compilation by Gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Gradle build with the source sets configured like so:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        groovy {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
    }
}
```

I have a `Jenkinsfile` in the root project directory that I would like to have compiled so that I can detect non-valid Groovy before it gets merged to the master branch and breaks the Jenkins build.

How can I add this single file to the source sets of the Gradle project for compilation? How can I ensure that Gradle compiles it even though it's not got a `.groovy` extension?

Comment: [JENKINS-34561](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-34561) might also be something to watch regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional `sourceSet` like this:

```groovy
sourceSets {
    jenkins {
        groovy {
            srcDir "$projectDir"
            include "JenkinsFile"
        }
    }
    main {
        groovy {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
    }
}
```

However, the problem is that you will not be able to compile a text file as Groovy. What you can do, however, is set up a task to create, compile, and delete a new `.groovy` file containing the contents of the Jenkins file before the groovy compilation. The final build file doing these things would look like this:

```groovy
apply plugin: 'groovy'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets {
    jenkins {
        groovy {
            srcDir "$projectDir"
            include "JenkinsFile.groovy"
        }
    }
    main {
        groovy {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
    }
}

task(createGroovyFile) {
    File jenkinsFile = new File("$projectDir/JenkinsFile")
    File groovyFile = new File("$projectDir/JenkinsFile.groovy")
    if(groovyFile.exists()) groovyFile.delete()
    groovyFile.newDataOutputStream() << jenkinsFile.readBytes()
}

task(deleteGroovyFile, type: Delete) {
    File groovyFile = new File("$projectDir/JenkinsFile.groovy")
    delete(groovyFile)
}


compileGroovy.dependsOn deleteGroovyFile
deleteGroovyFile.dependsOn compileJenkinsGroovy
compileJenkinsGroovy.dependsOn createGroovyFile

configurations {
    jenkinsCompile.extendsFrom compile
}

dependencies {
    compile   "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.10"
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the file _has_ to be named `Jenkinsfile`. Does the Groovy compiler or Gradle only recognize files that end in `.groovy`?

Comment: No, it won't. That is why I have provided the second solution that copies the jenkinsfile content to a groovy file, compiles it and deletes the file, all that before the compilation of the other groovy sources. Please have a closer look at the second code part I have provided.

Comment: can this detect method too large error?